# HDFS cannot obtain block length

Tags: hdfs

When I try to "hdfs dfs -cat myFile" from command line I get the exception "Cannot obtain block length for LocatedBlock" and there are many files affected by this issue.

Probably my HDFS cluster was in bad state.

Any solution for this problem please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means the file is being written yet, so the file needs to be closed, probably the data producer loses their connection with datanodes.

```
   hdfs debug recoverLease -path <path-of-the-file> [-retries <retry-times>]
```

Given a block-id you can get the file by executing:

```
hdfs fsck -blockId blk_523076021
```

Then you can recoverLease of this path.